# Validating 'between' rule for 'integer' -- javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using [validatorjs](https://github.com/skaterdav85/validatorjs/) for validation. There is a field `empId` which has to numeric and could have 4-12 digits.

This is how I had written the rule: 
`let rules = {
  empId: 'required|integer|between:0001,999999999999',
 };`

For testing I supply the value: 134333333333663, but to my surprise, that's not returning any error.

To surprise me more, this is what is happening:

I have two tests: `1. withValue(136) 2. withValue(1234) 3. withValue(134333333333663)`

`expected: 1. invalid 2. valid 3. invalid
actual: 1. invalid 2. valid 3. valid`

So the third test fails.

(This is the case I mentioned above).

I then changed the tests to this:

`1. withValue(136) 2. withValue(1234) 3. withValue(13)`

`expected: 1. invalid 2. valid 3. invalid
actual: 1. valid 2. valid 3. valid`

So essentially two tests fail now.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you try with min and max rule

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Tried, the problem with min & max is, it was always picking up the error for max, so for eg, withValue(136) will show error saying should be less than 12 digits, (which it already is) and the error message turned out to be ambiguous.

Comment: how come u getting false with 136. As size rule works on value(not length) for numeric values, it will be valid i think. or u wanna say ur rule is between:1000,999999999999

Comment: @MukulAnand Yeah correct, my bad! But I still don't understand the logic behind `withValue(134333333333663)` being valid.